# Difference between StringCoding.encode and CharsetEncoder.encode methods

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Could someone explain the difference between `java.lang.StringCoding.encode` and the `java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode` methods. I want to understand why the following test case fails due to the difference between them.

```
@Test
public void encodeTest()
{
    String testString = "<Con></Con>";
    byte[] bytesFromEncode = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(testString).array();
    byte[] bytesFromGetBytes = testString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    Assert.assertTrue("Byte arrays are different",
            Arrays.equals(bytesFromEncode, bytesFromGetBytes));
}
```

Comment: Did you look? `bytesFromEncode` has a trailing null byte for some reason.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, that's indeed my question :)